# Why is this integration proof incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I recently came across the fact that $\displaystyle\int_{\frac{m}{a}}^{\frac{n}{a}}\frac{f(ax)}{x}\,dx$ is independent of the value of $a$. This lead me to this integral here: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax) \cos(bx)}{x}\,dx$.

From the above result of independence, it is clear that:

$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(bx+ax)}{x}\,dx &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(bx-ax)}{x}\,dx\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(bx+ax)}{x}\,dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(bx-ax)}{x}\,dx &= 0\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(bx+ax) - \sin(bx-ax)}{x}\,dx&= 0\\
2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax) \cos(bx)}{x}\,dx&= 0\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax) \cos(bx)}{x}\,dx&= 0.
\end{align}
$

However, it's obvious that this is incorrect by counterexample, say $a = 2$ and $b = 1$. Where is the mistake in this proof? Is there a restriction on $a$ and $b$ that I need to take into consideration? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your $f$ when you apply the independence?

Comment: $f(x)$ is $\sin(x)$. For the LHS integral, the constant is $b+a$, for the RHS integral the constant is $b-a$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For finite $m$ and $n$, it is true that the value of

$$ \int_{m/a}^{n/a} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\, \mathrm dx $$

is independent of $x.$ But when you integrate to $\infty,$ you need to watch the sign.
In particular, if $p$ and $q$ have opposite signs, then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac np = - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac nq,$$

and therefore

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(px)}{x}\, \mathrm dx
 = \int_0^{-\infty} \frac{\sin(qx)}{x}\, \mathrm dx
 = - \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(qx)}{x}\, \mathrm dx. $$

Set $px = bx + ax$ and $qx = bx - ax$ in your calculations;
then for $a = 2$ and $b = 1,$ you have $p = 3$ and $q = -1,$
therefore

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2x) \cos(x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx
&= \frac12\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx
- \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(-x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx\right) \\
&= \frac12\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx\right) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx.
\end{align}
Neither side is zero.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you for this! So the restriction will be $b > a$ in this case

Comment: Yes, with that restriction the original calculation works.